# Changing the background colour of Magento 2 based on Luma

Tags: magento2, module, layout

I want to change the background colour of my magento 2 default page but it doesn't seem to be working. My code is:

**Pulsestorm/StartinWithLess/etc - module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="pulsestorm_StartingWithLess" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**Pulsestorm/StartinWithLess/view/frontend/layout - default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento
/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Pulsestorm_StartingWithLess::red-alert.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```

**Pulsestorm/StartinWithLess/view/frontend/web - red-alert.css**

```
body
{
background-color:#f00;
}
```

**Pulsestorm/StartingWithLess - registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pulsestorm_StartingWithLess',
    __DIR__
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Does your css loaded in your theme? Did you run static content deploy?

Comment: I did yeah but still doesn't work

Comment: Css is loading or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot Pulsestorm/StartingWithLess/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pulsestorm_StartingWithLess',
    __DIR__
);
```

Check casing (and spelling!) is the same for all uses of Pulsestorm and StartingWithLess

Install the module with

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Then set the store to developer mode so the static content does not need to be deployed

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: No luck i'm afraid

Comment: Edited my answer, also saw you spelled startinwithless wrong in the folder names

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the file `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less`, you will see a less variable called `@page__background-color`. You can override this variable in your theme.

Create a file in your theme at `web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors_extend.less`

```
@page__background-color: #FF0000;
```

Create a file in your theme at `web/css/source/_extend.less`

```
@import 'lib/variables/_colors_extend';
```

Then reload your files. You might need to:

```
rm -R pub/static/frontend
rm -R var/view_preprocessed
```

After this, refresh your page and you should be good to go.

One common mistake that developers make in Magento 2 is that they directly style common elements. However, it is my belief that they are breaking the system. Use the _extend.less file, which will be automatically imported by Magento, to import your custom file which contains overrides of only the specific variables you want to override while leaving the rest of the theme intact.